# Proof that there are more graphs with a labelling than graphs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This means that I need to know if there exists an injection from graphs with labellings to graphs and viceversa.

I don't know how to prove it or if it even is true. How can I even start?

Comment: This seems to be a completely different question than the one you originally asked. Also, it's unclear: what are you using as labels? And is this *really* what you mean to ask (there is a proper class of graphs, and a proper class of labelled graphs, so what you've asked is to compare the size of two proper classes; this can be done, but I'm not sure it's what you mean to ask, based on your previous questions)?

Comment: Yes, it actually is. I need to know if there are more labelled ones or not. My guess is that yes, there are more.

Comment: And I hope so..

Comment: The two proper classes have the same size - at least, there are injections both ways. It might help if you explained *why* you hope this is true ... (Also, again: what exactly are your labels? It won't make a difference, but it's still information to be included.)

Comment: And unless I miss my mark, [Cantor-Bernstein holds for classes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1124/does-cantor-bernstein-hold-for-classes), so they in fact have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you are labelling vertices in your labelled graphs with (say, we're allowing arbitrary sets as labels), the answer is: the two classes (of all graphs, and of all labelled graphs) are the same size.

- There is an injection from the class of labelled graphs to the class of graphs: send a labelled graph $G$ to the graph $\hat{G}$ with a single vertex, that vertex being $G$ itself, and no edges.
- There is an injection from the class of graphs to the class of labelled graphs: fix some label $l$, and given an unlabelled graph $G$ let $\hat{G}$ be the graph gotten from $G$ by labelling each vertex with $l$.
- Since [Cantor-Bernstein holds for classes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1124/does-cantor-bernstein-hold-for-classes), there is in fact a bijection between these two classes.